# auth.authenticate() keeps returning None

Tags: django

Here is my problem, I want to authenticate a custom AbstractBaseUser in.

```
if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print user
        if user is not None:
            ...
```

My user's informations are username: tom, password: tom.
When I check in the shell, I have a SimpleUser with these informations, so it exits. Now when I print user in the django console, it prints None. But, when I look at the informations Django has, it says

```
{'username': u'tom', u'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7fbb681fc650>, 'errors': ['Username/password error'], 'password': u'tom'}
```

So from what I see, username and password are correct. What's wrong ?

Edit : Creation of SimpleUser :

```
class SimpleUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    firstname = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    society = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password', 'society', 'email']
```

Edit 2 : Register view in views.py :

```
def registerview(request):
    firstname = ""
    lastname = ""
    username = ""
    password01 = ""
    password02 = ""
    email = ""
    society = ""
    errors = []
    hlinks = [("http://localhost:8000/", "Index"),
              ("http://localhost:8000/login", "Login"),
              ("http://localhost:8000/register", "Register"), ]
    if request.POST:
        firstname = request.POST['firstname']
        lastname = request.POST['lastname']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password01 = request.POST['password01']
        password02 = request.POST['password02']
        email = request.POST['email']
        society = request.POST['society']
        if (password01 != "" and password01 == password02 and firstname != "" and lastname != "" and username != "" and email != "" and society != ""):
            try:
                SimpleUser.objects.get(username=username)
            except SimpleUser.DoesNotExist:
                try:
                    SimpleUser.objects.get(email=email)
                except SimpleUser.DoesNotExist:
                    u = SimpleUser(firstname=firstname,
                                   lastname=lastname,
                                   username=username,
                                   password=password01,
                                   email=email,
                                   society=society)
                    u.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
            errors.append(
                "invalide user/pass")
        else:
            errors.append("fill all fields")
    c = {
        'headerlinks': hlinks,
        'footerlinks': footerlinks,
        'firstname': firstname,
        'lastname': lastname,
        'username': username,
        'email': email,
        'society': society,
        'errors': errors,
    }
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return jinja_render_to_response('registerview.jhtml', c)
```

Edit 3 : Add my backends.py :

```
from models import SimpleUser


class SimpleUserAuth(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = SimpleUser.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return username
        except SimpleUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = SimpleUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except SimpleUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: How did you create that user?

Comment: Can you login with this user and password to your django site via builtin authentification? If no - then you have wrong username/password. Also if you have password tom in db in password field - that is wrong too, there should be hashed password..

Comment: I edited with the code of the creation of the SimpleUser

Comment: Also, I don't hash the passwords for now because I'm just experimenting.

Comment: Django hash passwords when it do authentificate. You cant store password without hash. So if you password appear in database as tom - then it will not work. So how do you create this tom/tom user?

Comment: Edited with the register form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because when you are creating new user you are providing password as it is. So its stored as plain text in database, not as hashed value. And when you call authenticate function it will check against hashed value.
In your register you should either use `objects.create_user`  or set password with `set_password(password)`

Comment: All right, I understood, thanks :) I just did use set_password(). But now I have another error. Now I can register without any problem, and when I check in the admin pannel, I can see the hashed password provided by Django. But I cannot login with these informations.
I can login... With my Django superuser username and password.

Comment: All right, I created an authentication backend and added it in settings.py. Now my error is : AttributeError at /login/
'unicode' object has no attribute 'backend'.
I edit the question to add my authenthication backend

Comment: Well, nvm, when I use my authenticate backend I even have this error when trying to log in the admin pannel... And also, I'm forced to log in the admin pannel with my Simple User informations... Not my supe ruser informations. Gosh I'm lost ! :(

Comment: Your backend problem is because you return username but should return user

Comment: Oh thanks, Now I can log on my site. But I still have this problem : if I want to log on the admin panel, I need to enter SimpleUser informations. Which leads me to another error : 'SimpleUser' object has no attribute 'is_staff', which is normal. How can I specify to Django that I can only log to the admin panel with my superuser informations ?

Comment: you can have only 1 custom user model. And it will be used for all login, to site and to admin. You can try to create more complicated auth backend which will use different model, but you should just extend your user model with all attribs that required.
PS comments isnt a place for asking more and more questions..