# How to test login rest api in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-testing, django-tests

**Edit2:**  I got Why I am getting error, password miss-match. It is due to test database does not contain username and password itself.

**Edit1:**

Following  I am tried to write test cases for login api, when I write test out-side any class then it does not gives any error, But when I created class     `class TestCase(TestCase):` and define method `def test_login(self):`. It gives password miss-match, but outside same code running successfully.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
import json

#Creating test out side class


credential=dict()
c =Client()
credential["username"]="john"
credential["password"]="xxx"
response =c.put('/api/login', data=json.dumps(credential)) 

print("content")
print(response.content)

"""
{"message": "", "result": {"username": "john", "session_key": "xyz"}, "error": 0}
"""


print("session_key")
content = json.loads(response.content)
key = content['result']['session_key']
print key


#Creating test inside class


class TestCase(TestCase):
   def test_login(self):
      User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")
      credential=dict()
      c =Client()
      credential["username"]="john"
      credential["password"]="xxx"
      response =c.put('/api/login', data=json.dumps(credential))
      content=json.loads(response.content)
      print 'content'
      print content


     {u'message': u'Username and Password mismatch', u'result': {}, u'error': 1}
```

Here we can see message are different format for **successful**
`{"message": "", "result": {"username": "john", "session_key": "xyz"}, "error": 0}`

For **Unsuccessful**
`{u'message': u'username=john and password=xxx Username and Password mismatch', u'result': {}, u'error': 1}`.

login api is written like following, but when I define test inside class Test_login it is not going **if part** but go in **else part**. In else part I tried to print username and password with response. I am getting response like `{u'message': u'username=john and password=xxx Username and Password mismatch', u'result': {}, u'error': 1}`

Here we can see username and password are correct. Why it is not going **if part**. I research on net [get similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853695/auth-authenticate-keeps-returning-none). It had mentioned same problem. **So from what I see, username and password are correct. What's wrong ?**

**Backend Login api**

```
user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        print 'if user is not None:'
        msg=Some response 
    else:
      msg = strtemp+' username='+username+' and password='+password+' Username and Password mismatch'
```

So from what I see, username and password are correct. What's wrong ?

Comment: You are not creating any user outside test. Did you tried my answer? Im kind of sure that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think what is going on is that you are not setting password properly.

As you want to know, [django hashes the password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/) of model `User`.
Instead of calling `User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")`
all you should do is: `User.objects.create_user('john', password='xxx')`.

Apart from the answer I would like to tell you that you should not call your test class `TestCase`. Just to keep your code cleaner and probably avoid some future troubles.